# How to register a plugin to use inside a component library running by storybook?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, storybook, virtualscroll

I want to use a [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/blob/master/packages/vue-virtual-scroller/README.md) in my component library  which requires to be registered as a plugin via app.use() method.

However, the components lib has not app instance due it is running by storybook via `npm run storybook` and main.ts file exports only library components.

How can I add the plugin properly to the components lib?

Comment: Solution can be found there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004085/how-do-i-access-the-vue3-application-instance-from-a-storybook-story Market the current post as a duplicate.